# Question about the comma in Psalm 82:1

Tags: grammar-dikduk, tehilim-psalms, language

I've a short question about Psalm 82, verse 1.
The hebrew reads:  מִזְמוֹר לְאָסָף אֱלֹהִים נִצָּב בַּעֲדַת־אֵל בְּקֶרֶב אֱלֹהִים יִשְׁפֹּט

So how should one read these verse?
1. Is it that G-d will judge the elohim from the midst of the assembly of G-d?
2. Or is it that G-d takes stand in the assembly, and there, from the midst of elohim, He judges.
3. Or is it that He will judge with the elohim?

As there are no punctuation symbols such as the comma in the Hebrew verse, but it makes a lot of difference to the meaning of the verse.

Comment: "As there are no punctuation symbols such as the comma in the Hebrew verse" yes there are.  They're called trop.

Comment: the trop indicates that a separate idea (such as after a comma or a semicolon) begins at "bkerev"  אֱ‍ֽלֹהִ֗ים נִצָּ֥ב בַּעֲדַת־אֵ֑ל בְּקֶ֖רֶב אֱלֹהִ֣ים יִשְׁפֹּֽט so choice 2 would be right. The Judaica Press version has "God stands in the congregation of God; in the midst of the judges He will judge"

Comment: @rosends That should be an answer.

Comment: @Heshy aren't those added, just like the nikkud?

Comment: @rosends aren't those added, just like the nikkud?

Comment: @levi I'm not sure what you mean by "added".

Comment: Theoretically, the trops are not obligating, tons of interpretations in the Gemmora override them all. That's the beauty of Hebrew that everyone is free to twist it to suit his needs.

Comment: @rosends Originally there weren’t any vowels and thropes to be found inside a Torah scroll. Untill the Masorites/Masoretes added them.

Comment: @Levi they are still not found in a Torah scroll, but they also weren't invented by the Masoretes. https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/817346/jewish/Who-Made-Up-the-Way-We-Sing-the-Torah.htm